# Bubble sorting for linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort a singly linked list using bubble sort. If there is a simple mistake then please pardon. Please tell me where I am going wrong. Program stops unexpectedly when I try to do this.

```
void sortBubble()
{
      Node *i=start,*j=start;Node *temp;Node* prev=start;Node* agla;
      while(i->next!=NULL)
      {
           cout<<"\nhello 1";
           j=i;
           agla=j->next;
           while(agla!=NULL)
           {
                temp=NULL;temp->next=NULL;
                cout<<"\nhello2";

                if(*(j) > *(agla))
                {
                     temp=agla->next;
                     agla->next=j;
                     prev->next=agla;
                     prev=agla;
                     agla=j->next;
                     j->next=temp;
                }
                else{
                     prev=j;
                     j=agla;
                     agla=j->next;}
                }
                prev=i;
                i=i->next;
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Might help if the definition of `Node` and related operator overrides were included...

Comment: I dont post my homework problems on Stack overflow. Its just out of my passion. @Shahbaz

Comment: @MohitSehgal, we do get a lot of homework questions on SO, believe it or not. Questions regarding basic questions like this usually tend to be of that kind. That is why we ask.

Comment: Its totally right but this one is  not homework.!! :-) @Shahbaz

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a linked list using bubble-sort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522121/how-to-sort-a-linked-list-using-bubble-sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first obvious mistake that absolutely leads to program crash is:

```
       while(agla!=NULL)
       {
            temp=NULL;temp->next=NULL;
```

You are setting a variable to `NULL`, then setting its fields. A null pointer points to nowhere, so you cannot edit its contents.

Remove `temp->next=NULL;`

---

### Edit:

Your program logic is not correct. You ruin the list after a few iterations of the loop and the program sticks in an infinite loop with mixed up pointers.

In bubble sort, we iterate through the items several times. In each iteration, the largest item is bubbled up to the end of the list. After first iteration, we are sure that the largest element is at the end of the list. After second iteration, we are sure that the second largest element is before the last element of the list, and so on.
You repeat this process until all the items are on their places:

```
int getListSize(Node* start)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(start != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        start = start->next;
    }
    return count;
}

void bubbleSort(Node *&start) // <-- Pass a reference to pointer, because we may need to modify the start pointer.
{
    int size = getListSize(start);
    int i = 0;

    while(size--)
    {
        Node
            *current = start,
            *prev = NULL; // We are at the beginnig, so there is no previous node.

        while(current->next != NULL) // We have at least one node (size > 0) so `current` itself is not NULL.
        {
            Node *after = current->next;
            if((*current) > (*after))
            {
                //swap the items
                current->next = after->next;
                after->next = current;
                if (prev == NULL) // we are at the beginning
                    start = after;
                else
                    prev->next = after;

                prev = after;
            }
            else
            {
                prev = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We repeat the "bubbling up" process `size` times. This is not the most efficient way, since we even compare the items that are already sorted. A more efficient way is to sort until no new swapping occurs:

```
void bubbleSort(Node *&start) // <-- Pass a reference to pointer, because we may need to modify the start pointer.
{
    int size = getListSize(start);
    int i = 0;

    Node *lastSwapped = NULL;

    while(size--)
    {
        Node
            *current = start,
            *prev = NULL, // We are at the beginnig, so there is no previous node.
            *currentSwapped = NULL;

        while(current->next != lastSwapped) // We have at least one node (size > 0) so `current` itself is not NULL.
        {
            Node *after = current->next;
            if((*current) > (*after))
            {
                //swap the items
                current->next = after->next;
                after->next = current;
                if (prev == NULL) // we are at the beginning
                    start = after;
                else
                    prev->next = after;

                prev = after;
                currentSwapped = current;
            }
            else
            {
                prev = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
        }

        if (currentSwapped == NULL)
            break; // No swapping occured. The items are sorted.
        else
            lastSwapped = currentSwapped;
    }
}
```

[This is the complete working program](https://gist.github.com/4066561)

Comment: Thanks alot.!! this is absolutely fine.!!

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the elements by simply doing `*(j) > *(agla)`, I'm not sure how that builds since both `j` and `agla` are pointers to structures. Structures cannot be compared directly.

Comment: He probably overloaded `operator>` for the structure or class `Node`.

Comment: yes Node is a class in which i have properly overloaded the operator >