# Why is this Bubblesort with Double Linked List In C not sorting?

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort

I'm trying to sort a doubly linked list using a bubblesort in C. However, the list returned is the same list I put in. Example [1,2,4,8,0,3] -> [1,2,4,8,0,3]

```
void bublesort(slist_t *list){
    list_item_t *curr = NULL;
    curr = list->head;
    if(curr == NULL){
       printf("\nList is empty.");
    }
    while(curr->next != NULL && curr->value > curr->next->value){
       curr = swap(curr, curr->next, list);
    }
    while(curr->prev != NULL){
        if(curr->value < curr->prev->value){
            bublesort(list);
        }
    }

}

list_item_t *swap(list_item_t *item1, list_item_t *item2, slist_t *list){
    item1->next = item2->next;
    item2->next = item1;
    item2->prev = item1->prev;
    item1->prev = item2;
    if(item1 == list->head){
        list->head = item2;
    }
    if(item2 == list->tail){
        list->tail = item1;
    }
    return item2;
}
```

Comment: State what is happening and what you expect to happen?

Comment: @Digital_Reality well, as stated in the title, Bubblesort should sort but it doesn't sort. In other words, when I run bubble sort I get the same list back out that i put in. I'd expect bubblesort to... well sort.

Comment: You don't need to allocate memory for `instanceList` if you are not using that memory. And also write comments to what you're doing.

Comment: You do not need to allocate *any* memory when bubble sorting an existing linked list. With each pass the last node is removed and pushed into a separate list headed by a pointer that is initially NULL. as soon as a no swap condition happens the remaining list is sorted and the two can be joined to form the final list (this condition will happen by-default when there is one node left in the source list if it hasn't happened already). [See this answer for a more detailed explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522121/how-to-sort-a-linked-list-using-bubble-sort/19524059#19524059).