# linked list sort problems

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to use a bubble sort to sort a linked list. I can't just swap the values inside the nodes either. I've been drawing pictures trying to figure out how to do it myself without help, but I'm starting to get a head ache and can't figure out why this wont work.

```
void sort_ascending(struct node ** head){
  int x;
  struct node*temp;
  struct node*temp2;
  x = length(*head)+1;    //checks if more than one node is in the list
  if(x < 2){
    printf("1 or less\n");
    //free(temp);
    return;
  }
  printf("longer than 1\n");
  printf("%d %d\n", (*head)->val, (*head)->next->val);
  if((*head)->val > (*head)->next->val){
    printf("needs to sort!\n");
    temp = (*head)->next->next; //sets temp to the node after the two nodes being swapped
    printf("test1\n");
    temp2 = (*head); //sets temp2 to the node1
    printf("test2\n");
    *head = (*head)->next; //changes head to point at node2 instead of node1
    printf("test3\n");
    (*head)->next = temp2; //sets node2 to point to node1
    (*head)->next->next = temp; //sets node2 to point back into the list
    printf("test4\n");
    //free(temp);
  }
}
```

Right now I'm just trying to sort two nodes. After I can get this working I'll make it into a loop. For some reason, it isnt even sorting the first two elements.

Here are some of my other functions to help with understanding:

struct definition:

```
struct node {
int val;
struct node *next;
```

};

other functions:

```
void push(struct node ** headRef, int data){
struct node* newNode =  malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //alocates space on heap
printf("pushed node\n");
newNode->val = data;//sets data value
printf("%d\n", newNode->val);
newNode->next = *headRef; // The '*' to dereferences back to the real head
*headRef = newNode; // ditto
```

};

```
void print(struct node * head, int length){
int x = 0;
printf("tried to print\n");
//struct node*temp = head;

//while(head->next != NULL){
while (x < length + 1){
    printf("ran loop\n");
    printf("%d\n", head->val);
    printf("got number\n");
    head = head->next;
    x++;
}
printf("done with loop\n");
```

}

```
int main(){
char ans;
int num;
struct node *head = NULL;
do {
    do {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        push(&head, num);//Can change to append for back

        printf("Do you want another num (y or n): ");
        scanf("%1s", &ans);
    } while (ans == 'y');

    printf("Sort ascending or descending (a or d)? ");
    scanf("%1s", &ans);
    if(ans == 'a') sort_ascending(&head);
    //else if(ans == 'd') sort_descending(&head);

    print(head, length(head));

    printf("Do you want to do this again (y or n)? ");
    scanf("%1s", &ans);
    if (ans == 'y') clear(&head);

} while (ans == 'y');


return 0;
```

}

```
int length(struct node* head){
int length = 0;
//struct node*temp = head;
printf("tried to find length\n");
while (head->next != NULL){
    length++;
    head = head->next;
}
printf("%d\n", length + 1);
return length;
```

}

Comment: How are you calling this function? How are you testing to see if this works?

Comment: after I have created two nodes, say one with a value of 5 and one of 6, I call this function to sort the nodes I have created. If it rearranges them, ill know it works

Comment: I know you understand how sorting works. :) I want to know 1) how you're constructing your nodes (show us your code), and 2) if you're inspecting values in a debugger or printing them out to screen to test if this works.

Comment: @WernerHenze While your malloc statement is true, the OP did state that he's only trying to sort the first two elements right now, and will add the loops later.

Comment: Thanks for the malloc info, I will remove them.

Comment: I guess I never really stated what my true problem is. When I try to sort two elements, it doesn't sort them, they seem to stay in the same spot.

Comment: @KshitijMehta I updated my question, I hope that helps. edit: added main. cant believe I forgot that one hah

Comment: For some reason, the length function would always return the size of the list 1 smaller than what it was, so that was my compensation.

Comment: The compensation is correct, but you need to return the compensated value as well. You're just printing it out.

Comment: Well I was compensating for it each time I used it, but your method is definitely easier, thanks!

Comment: @user2951303 I think you're solving a wrong problem. With linked lists, its better to keep them in order during your inserts. And if you can't because of some reason, may be think of a different data structure to fit better for what you're doing.

Comment: Ok well I'm not sure exactly why it worked for you haha. But the good news is after some more debugging, I'm pretty sure I fixed it.

When I was switching around pointers, I think I created a pointer loop or something, but I got it working. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: And that would explain the problem with length, thanks! :)

Comment: Fwiw, bubblesorting a linked list isn't entirely intuitive if you're truly sorting by pointer manipulation; not value-swapping. An example of how it can be done  [can be found in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19524059/1322972). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's sum it up.

The function length is off by 1.

```
int length(struct node* head){
    int length = 0;
    while (head != NULL){
        ++length;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return length;
}
```

The function print is printing too much.

```
void print(struct node * head, int length){
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < length; ++x){
        printf("%d\n", head->val);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

And your scanf is corrupting the memory. scanf with "%1s" is expecting a pointer to at least two chars, one to store and the trailing null byte. So you need to either provide two chars (`char ans[2];`) or, the better solution, just read one character as a character.

```
char ans;
scanf("%c", &ans);
```

Also, as said, [don't cast the return value of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) if you are programming in C.

If you wonder why I changed your postfix ++ (like `x++`) to prefix ++ (like `++x`): I am a C++ programmer and for C++ it is recommended to prefer prefix ++ over postfix ++ for performance reasons (not relevant for int or pointers, but for complex types like iterators).