# Bubble sort linked list

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort

I have these two structs that are building an linked list:

```
struct Element {
    int value;
    struct Element *next;
};

struct List {
    struct Element *first;
};
```

Now I want to sort the linked list with a bubble sort. I implemented the method sortList that compares the value of the current element with the value of the next element. If the value of the next element is bigger than the current one they have to swap. But at this moment it doesn't work correctly.

```
void sortList(List *list) {
    Element *current = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    current = list->first;
    Element *nextElement = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    nextElement = current->next;
    Element *tmp = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    tmp = NULL;

    int changed = 1;
    while (changed) {
        changed = 0;
        for (current; (current != NULL) && (nextElement != NULL); ) {
            if (current->value > nextElement->value) {
                tmp = current->next;
                current->next = nextElement->next;
                nextElement->next = tmp;
                changed = 1;
            }
            current = current->next;
            nextElement = nextElement->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? The basic approach seems valid; however I suggest moving the swap operation to a seperate function.

Comment: The list isn't sorted correctly.

Input: 1 4 3 2 6
Output: 1 4 2 6 3

Comment: Is the implementation able to sort a list with two elements in the wrong order?

Comment: No, one element is missing.

Input: 5 2
Output: 5

Comment: Please try to factor out the swapping in a separete function. What makes the implementation a bit difficult is the fact that the list is singly linked, which means that actually a reference to the element _before_ the element which is to be swapped with its successor is needed for the swap. This causes a special case if the first element is swapped with its successor, as the first element doesn't have a predecessor but is referenced by `List`. Usually, this is addressed by an artificial element before the first element. Iguess that the swap as implemented does not handle this case correctly.

Comment: node and Link replacement of is incorrect. it is easy to replace the `value`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a linked list using bubble-sort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522121/how-to-sort-a-linked-list-using-bubble-sort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the for,before restarting the while, you have to set current and nextElement pointing the beginning of the list! Or they dont change and the test condition of the for fail immediatly.
Also, what's the point of the mallocs? you use current,next and temp only as pointer to node, not as real node, I think that you can delete all of them.
And you can rewrite the for as a while with the condtion only, it's more readable.
Sorry for my english.

EDIT: as written under the question you need to change the pointer inside list. I think that the easiest way is to move the lower element at the beginning of the list immediatly, and change the the head of the list to point this element. After that sort the rest of the  list.

Comment: Now i changed the things you said from the first paragraph. Now the function looks like this: http://pastie.org/9758554

I don't understand everything of your EDIT-part. Could you change the code?

Comment: ok I change the code. The point is to update the list->first value to point the REAL first value. In the 5 2 list example you can see the problem of don't doing this, the list is sorted, and become 2 5 BUT list->first point to 5, so the thing before 5 are lost!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the program is sorting an existing list, there's no reason to be allocating nodes in sortList, it should just be manipulating pointers to existing nodes.

When swapping nodes, the pointer that points to the current node needs to be updated, which may be list.first or Element.next. Using a pointer to pointer makes this a bit easier.

```
struct Element **ppcur;  /* pointer to list->first or element->next */
/* ... */
    if(list == NULL || list->first == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for(ppcur = &(list->first); pnxt = (pcur = *ppcur)->next;
        ppcur = &((*ppcur)->next)){
    /* ... */
```